# Cardano-graphql / Hasura - not found in type: 'query_root'

Tags: cardano-graphql

I found this github issue: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/issues/507 discussing how to get assets of an address at a certain block using cardano-graphql / Hasura.

When I run the "SDL Version" of the query, as mentioned in the github issue, on the referenced page (https://graphql-api.mainnet.dandelion.link/), it works just fine.

When I try the same query on my cardano-graphql stack in Hasura, I get this error message:

> field "paymentAddresses" not found in type: 'query_root'

I searched for similar errors, and it seems to have to do with permissions, but I can't figure out which permissions are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the **hasura console** or the **apollo graphql console**?

That query won't be available through the hasura console since paymentAddresses is not a postgres table that hasura directly binds to. The apollo graphql server actually queries hasura, transforms the data and then returns it. You can see [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/blob/master/packages/api-cardano-db-hasura/src/executableSchema.ts) that payment addresses calls the `getPaymentAddressSummary` function on the [hasura client](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/blob/master/packages/api-cardano-db-hasura/src/HasuraClient.ts).

Comment: I just now realized the difference between the two consoles. Thanks. All works when entering it in the correct console.